# I need to rename a file just created, but before the type extension

Tags: ruby

I've got the following variable:

```
filepath = "test.tmx"
```

I need to add `_out` at the end of the name of the file generated, but before the extension. So far, I've written this, but it's incorrect:

```
File.open(filepath+"-"+language_code+"_out", "w")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need minimal sample input. Also, your code is not syntactically correct. Please fix it. See "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Also, since TMX is an XML format, you shouldn't try to use regex, you should use a parser like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer to your edited question is simple.

```
filepath = "test.tmx"
filepath_before_extension = File.basename(filepath, '.tmx')
# => "test"

puts "#{filepath_before_extension}_out.tmx"
# => test_out.tmx
```

Or:

```
puts filepath.sub(/\.tmx$/, '_out.tmx')
# => test_out.tmx
```

The answer to your original question is only slightly more complex.

If I understand correctly you're trying to combine `filepath` and `language_code` to form a filename like this:

```
adidas_174_Generic-en-AR_out.tmx
```

...but instead you're getting this:

```
adidas_174_Generic.tmx-en-AR_out
```

In that case, it's the same, except you add `language_code` to the output:

```
language_code = "es-AR"
filepath = "adidas_174_Generic.tmx"
filepath_before_extension = File.basename(filepath, '.tmx')
# => "adidas_174_Generic"

puts "#{filepath_before_extension}-#{language_code}_out.tmx"
# => adidas_174_Generic-es-AR_out.tmx
```

Or:

```
puts filepath.sub(/\.tmx$/, "-#{language_code}_out.tmx")
# => adidas_174_Generic-es-AR_out.tmx
```

Comment: Dear downvoter: Please leave a comment explaining the reason for your downvote. If my answer is lacking I would appreciate the opportunity to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

First, extract the file [extension](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/File.html#method-c-extname) and [basename](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/File.html#method-c-basename) into a couple of variables:

```
# Get the file extension
ext = File.extname(filepath)

# Get the file's basename (without extension)
basename = File.basename(filepath, '.*')
```

Then you can construct the new filename using them:

```
File.open(basename + language_code + '_out' + ext, 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse your filename to separate the base from extension using the standard library's `File`, and then re-assable.

This should work:

```
languages_list = ["es-AR", "es-CL", "es-CO", "es-MX", "es-PE"]
filepath = "adidas_174_Generic.tmx"
text = File.read(filepath)

languages_list.each do |language_code|
  puts language_code
  replace = text.gsub('<tuv xml:lang="es-PA">', "<tuv xml:lang=\"#       {language_code}\">")

  file_base = File.basename filepath, ".*"
  file_extension = File.extname filepath

  new_file_path = file_base+language_code+"_out"+file_extension

  File.open(new_file_path, "w") {|file| file.puts  replace}
```